# Load Sharepoint snap-in on client

Tags: 2010, powershell

Can I somehow load the Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell snap-in on a client pc, so I can use the intellisense feature of the PowerShell ISE while I am working offline?
I understand that I cannot run the code on the client, all I need is to make the code eg on the train, and when I arrive in the office I am already an hour ahead with the work.

Answer (score 0):

You can`t load the Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell snap-in on a client machine because it uses the Server side object and requires to run only on SharePoint servers.

But you can connect using SharePoint client libraries. Below are some of the links which can help you to get started.

[Download the SharePoint 2010 client object model components](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=21786)

[Tricks to connect to the SP 2010 using CSOM from the Powershell](https://blog.vgrem.com/2013/11/19/some-tips-and-tricks-of-using-sharepoint-client-object-model-in-powershell/)